# How to give a name to a docker volume mounted from an external drive

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am trying to create a volume on an external drive . It works with the following command

```
docker run -t -i -v /mnt/mydrive:/var/  ubuntu
```

But with the above command, I am not able to provide a name to the volume. How can I create a named volume mounted to an external drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a volume and then configure the container to use it:

```
$ docker volume create my_volume --driver local --opt device=/mnt/mydrive
$ docker run -t -i -v my_volume:/var/  ubuntu
```

Check [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) for more options and details.

**NB:** Drive should be mounted first in your system. But if you want to handle that also through docker, check [driver specific options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options) where you can specify ip, write mode, file system etc.

Comment: TN ..thanks for editing the question and sharing your inputs. I did try the above commands.I was able to create the volume but when I try to attach it to a container I get an error.I have edited the question

Comment: Please don't edit the question based on answers, it causes inconsistency of the content. Either You ask new question or write as comment here. Regarding the new error: you have to mount first the external driver in your system then write the commands above where `/mnt/mydrive` is where you mounted the drive.

Answer (score 3):

**[Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)** (what you are doing) is not the same as [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

[image: https://docs.docker.com/storage/images/types-of-mounts-bind.png]

So you cannot assign a bind mount volume a name.